# Calculate field value based on another field value with Rules

Tags: 7, entities, commerce, rules

I am using Drupal 7 and Commerce.

I have Product display where is custom field called **Stock** (field_stock). This field holds stock value (integer) for Product.

In Product display I have Product Variations. Variations has custom field called **Stock Value** (field_stock_value).

When adding new Product display and setting field **Stock** to value 10. And then adding first Variation and setting field **Stock Value** to 6. And to second Variation field **Stock Value** to 4.

I need to have rules which decreases Stock field from Product display. So it is simple: take value from **Stock Value** field and reduce that amount from **Stock** field.

But I have not succeeded to make working rules for that. Any help needed. Thanks!

Comment: The main problem here is that I cant get field_stock to show in Actions. Because cant add condition "Content is type of" because there is no Node data selector. And that is because I have to have Event "Completing the checkout process"

Comment: I think I understand your missing event challenge. However, when you're "adding a variation" (1st or 2nd, doesn't matter), what kind of information (which fields, ie their machine names) do you have available that indicate which "product display" that variation is about (related to)?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field)

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You
>   can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the
>   database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the
>   fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use
>   requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss
>   Army knife of CCK fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

Check [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) too

> Define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.

Comment: none of these solutions are work!!